# Incompatible types Class<T> and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method that looks like this:

```
private <T> List<T> get(Class<T> mClass, String s)
   return Arrays.asList(a.get(s).map(mClass).orElse(null));
}
```

The method `map()` expects a `Class<T>` as argument and returns an array of Type `T`.

I `get(Class<T> mClass, String s)` with `PDTO[].class` and get the following error

> Wrong first type argument. Required java.lang.Class

Why?

Comment: Please show the code the the `get(s)` method. And besides, what's the type of `a` and where is it declared?

Comment: Quite difficult without the rest of the code but as a guess; are you sure `map(mClass)` returns and array of type T as the arrays in Java don't support `orElse`.  Are you returning an java.util.Optional?